# VB.Net Label and radio button problems

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, label

I am creating a VB.net program where kids can answer exercises on multiplication. I have a problem cause my professor wants me to print the results of the exercises where the kids answer 10 randomized multiplication problems . the summary which he wants me to create should contain the questions, the kid's answer to every question, and if it is wrong, the correct answer should also be prompted. the problem is, the questions are randomly generated integers displayed at the same label control, how am I gonna call every question if that's the case? well, that's just the first problem. my second problem is about radio buttons, see, there are three difficulty levels, the easy, medium, and hard level. every difficulty level has 10 questions. what I want to happen is that when a kid finishes answering one level, the radiobutton that corresponds to it should be disabled. here's the picture for my problem to make sense to you . 
[image: multiplication exercise]

and the summary must be contained on a different form.

Comment: Each time you generate a new formula, capture the generated values from the screen and save away with the correct result. When the student answers it, save that too.

Comment: uhm , how am I gonna capture it ? am I supposed to save it into a variable, an array? or something like that ? how am I gonna call it in another form? thanks tho .

Comment: Are you looking for scrape the information off the screen from within the application, or from another application? If you are in control of the application and code, find the point at which the random numbers are generated and placed into the labels, and capture them then. You could use some form level variables and pass to other forms that way.

Comment: uhm, if im gonna generate 10 random numbers, then it would mean 10 different global variables to serve as temporary storage ?

Comment: Add each equation into a string array as you go. Print or Parse that array when complete. 1 array for each difficulty level.

Comment: uhm sorry, but what do you mean by 'Print or Parse that array when complete' , sir?

Comment: Is this your application? Can you find the point in the code where the numbers are put into the labels?

Comment: You say "my professor wants me to print the results", do you mean actually print to a printer, or show the results in another form?

Comment: "the problem is, the questions are randomly generated integers displayed at the same label control, how am I gonna call every question if that's the case?" That is basic programming. Learn how to use arrays and variables. This really isn't so much a problem as it is a lack of programming knowledge. Sorry.

Comment: thankyou, Im sorry I just started programming 3 yrs ago. I know I lack experience but Im willing to learn. Thank you . PS. - figured a solution to this myself. thanks @Mort tho for your suggestion :)